# Removing snapshots created by lucreate

Tags: solaris, opensolaris

I patched my Solaris 10 system recently and as part of the lucreate process (creating the BE on the same zpool), a snapshot was created for one my zones.

The problem I'm running into is every night 15GB of backups are deleted from that zone, and it's causing the zone to start to run low on space since that snapshot is storing all that data (which I don't need, but I can't find a way to exclude a specific folder from a zfs snapshot). Another few days the zpool will be full causing larger issues.

Is it safe to delete snapshot? I understand that if I were need to activate the previous boot environment, this zone couldn't revert back, but any other issues?

```
NAME                                  USED  AVAIL  REFER  MOUNTPOINT
pool                                  178G  89.3G    24K  /pool
pool/server1                          178G  89.3G   147G  pool/server1
pool/server1@BE2                      31.7G     -   138G  -
pool/server1-BE1                      7.44M 89.3G   138G  pool/server1-BE1
```

Tomorrow, that snapshot will increase another 15GB or so.

```
zfs destroy -R pool/server1@BE2
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can delete the snapshot and as you said, you lose that previous boot environment.  There should be no other issues.

ZFS snapshots are all-or-nothing.  You can't exclude things.